# change listbox item background on button event

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, buttonclick

i'm working on winform , where I'm showing couple of id's as string in listbox.

User  also have 3 buttons by which, can assign what to do with this id's.

What I want to acomplish is, when user select specific listbox item and next click on specfic button, it will also changing background or font color of this item. Of course every single button have it own color.

```
public List<string> listaUslugJednorazowych = new List<string>(); 
    public notFoundsForm(List<string> notFoundList)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listBox1.DataSource = notFoundList;

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listaUslugJednorazowych.Add(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
        listBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
        listBox1.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(listBox_DrawItem);
    }

    void listBox_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Index == listBox1.SelectedIndex)
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, e.Bounds);

        }
        if (e.Index > -1)
        {

            using (Brush textBrush = new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor))
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(listBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, textBrush, e.Bounds.Location);
            }
        }
    }
```

above code is what I maded instructed by severals tip's from google but still it's not the thing I want to get.

How do I should do this right? Right now all I want to change the color by button_1Click.

Comment: Some things I notice. 1. You dont have to set `DrawMode` of listbox every time the button is clicked. Set it either at design time or when form is loading, **once** 2. You dont have to add an event handler for every button click. Once you set the `drawmode` the function `listBox_DrawItem`(designer->properties->events double click at `drawItem`) will be called automatically.

Comment: ok but the problem is , that after once I click button1 - drawing will be always running. I mean- when i'm clicking at button1 drawing mode is turned on to colorize EVERY selected item , even when U change selected item ( not change selected item and then click button ).

Comment: You need to store somehow the **index** of the selected item in mouse click, so in your paint you check and paint only this index and not the other items.